# Why are the node attributes in the Test Kitchen generated dna.json not being included in my chef-shell execution?

Tags: chef-infra, test-kitchen, chef-zero

Using the following commands I am able to get chef-shell to execute, pulling in all of my cookbooks and data bags:

```
kitchen login
cd /tmp/kitchen
sudo -E /opt/chef/embedded/bin/chef-zero -d
sudo knife cookbook upload -a -c client.rb
sudo knife upload data_bags -c client.rb
sudo -E /opt/chef/bin/chef-shell -z -c client.rb -j dna.json -o "role-web-server::default"
```

However, I get the following exception:

```
Chef::Exceptions::InvalidDataBagItemID
--------------------------------------
Data Bag items must have an id matching /^[\.\-[:alnum:]_]+$/, you gave: nil

Cookbook Trace:
---------------
  /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/chef-vault/libraries/chef_vault_item.rb:44:in `chef_vault_item'

... other stacktrace...
```

The value `nil` is provided to the `chef_vault_item` function, when I have an appropriate value specified in my `.kitchen.yml`, and it's in the `dna.json` that I passed in to chef-shell. I know the value is there because my regular 'kitchen converge' finds the attribute just fine.

Why are the node attributes in the Test Kitchen generated `dna.json` not being included in my chef-shell execution? Am I going about it all wrong to get chef-shell to run inside of a Test Kitchen VM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-z` option for chef-shell doesn't automatically involve the chef zero/local-mode systems. It predates those by a bunch, `-z` is the short form of `--client` which just uses the config in the `client.rb`. You would need to modify that to point at Chef Zero.

Are you sure you mean to be using `chef-shell`? It sounds more like you mean to use `chef-client` there.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I was hoping to use chef-shell to diagnose what was going on with some issues with a chef-client run of a role cookbook that depended on a number of cookbooks I'm working with. I also tried with -S http://localhost:8889 and it did not work. 

Am I barking up the wrong tree trying to use chef-shell? I just figured it would be a good tool to interactively observe what's going on in a converge...

Comment: You could use it, but you need to reconfigure a bunch of stuff. Probably easier to just use logging output to trace the execution.

Comment: I did finally work through my problem without it via debug level run. Before I mark this as answered, are you able to point to what you'd need to reconfigure in order to get it to include those attributes in the chef-shell run?

Comment: Thanks for the time spent in the earlier response. Although it's not fully answered, your pointing to logging output led me to a solution so I'll mark it answered :)